# Python: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributeerror

I'm very much new to Python, essentially being pushed into a new project with no knowledge of the language whatsoever. I've gone over a number of tutorials to get a gist of the syntax and some of the functions, but I'm currently stumped on something that seems pretty basic.

I have a class GeoLocationHandlerObj in GeoLocationSolver.py which has a method 'myMethod':

```
class GeoLocationHandlerObj(object):
  def __init__(self, connector, debug=0):
    self._debug = debug
    self.locator = GeoLocationSolverObj(connector)
    return(None)

  def close(self):
    ...
    return(None)

  def getAdr(self, point, lang):
    ...
    return(None)

  def getCom(self, point, lang):
    ...
    return(None)

  def getHmp(self, point, lang):
    ...
    return(None)

  def myMethod(self):
    print "test"
    return(None)
```

I import it and try to call myFunction:

```
import sys
import os
import psycopg2
import string
import json
import socket
import random

from GeoPackage.GeoCoding.GeoLocationSolver import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
  connector = GeoPSConnectorObj(...)
  handler = GeoLocationHandlerObj(connector)
  handler.myMethod()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'GeoLocationHandlerObj' object has no attribute 'myMethod'.

What am I missing in order to successfully call this method?

Comment: If you are learning, please learn python3

Comment: What do you get from `print(dir(handler))`?

Comment: Why are you using the return(None) in the __init__ function?  and try using a different name than handler.. you might be importing that from one the libraries

Comment: Exactly same code you post get the error or you change something for any property reason?

Comment: @roganjosh I get the following from dir: ['SolveGeoLocation', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_debug', 'close', 'getAdr', 'getCom', 'getHmp', 'getKpt', 'locator']. I can see that some functions (getAdr, getCom, getHmp, ...) are being shown here, but other functions of this class (myMethod, getBld..) are not, even though they are defined in the same way.  What could cause this?

Comment: @DaFanat I'm really not sure, the return(None) in the init was done by someone else who has already left. Most of the functions in this class are being successfully called by a .wsgi web service, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried renaming handler as well, but that also didn't work.

Comment: Well, there's a couple of things that could be going on. Perhaps changes you have made are not active in the web server because you will need to re-launch whatever server you're using. Or, you have a cached version of the old module through some other quirk of how you're working on the code base (like interactive IDEs or something) so you can try forcibly reloading the module with `reload(GeoPackage.GeoCoding.GeoLocationSolver)`. `import *` is generally considered poor practice btw, reference the class with `import GeoPackage.GeoCoding.GeoLocationSolver as gls` might be better

Comment: `import *` clutters the namespace and you don't necessarily know with what. With my suggestion, you would then reference the class with `connector = gls.GeoPSConnectorObj(...)` then you're explicit which module that class comes from.

Comment: Presumably it can't be a web server issue because you modifies the code in order to get the `print` results actually so it looks like an older version of the module might be cached

Comment: @roganjosh that seems to likely be what's going on. I changed the code to use import as and put reload(gls) right after the import, but still I get the same result when I print dir(handler)..

Comment: Very strange. If I totally empty the GeoLocationSolver.py file and save it, then run my test script where I call some older function of the class (eg. SolveGeoLocation), it still works, and the dir() still shows exactly the same. Even after doing a reload() on the module. And this is just testing locally on my PC in visual studio code.

Comment: I think your issue might be quite complex. It's possible that the previous employee published the module as library on the PATH and the file you're working with is not the file that python finds when doing the import. I'm not sure we can suggest more than that sorry. Is there anyone at work who might know about the history of that project?

Comment: using `import GeoPackage.GeoCoding.GeoLocationSolver as gls`,  `print(gls.__file__)` is the path correct?

Comment: @e.s. I think you just saved my day. Indeed the path was pointing to a second instance of the project. I'll have to check the path settings to see what is going on here..

Comment: @roganjosh thanks for your insight, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, adding two new methods to a previously existing class, trying to call the methods would fail because of "object has no attribute".  Finally chased it down to the previous dev using a different tabs/spaces configuration from my editor.  Once I changed my new code to use the same configuration as the previous code, Python was able to reference the functions.